# How to merge multiple table or matrix into one in R code

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

This is my first question, and it is related to R coode.

I have a situation where I have 50 (10X10) data frames. These are item and count on various dates. A simplified example of two matrix:

```
  > Day1
     name count
  1 Item1   231
  2 Item2   222
  3 Item3   453

  > dim(Day1)
  [1] 3 2

  > str(Day1)

  'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
   $ name : Factor w/ 3 levels "Item1","Item2",..: 1 2 3
   $ count: num  231 222 453

  > Day2
   name count
  1 Item1   111
  2 Item4   765
  3 Item3   212
```

So a merge should look like this:

```
     > Total
     name  D1  D2
  1 Item1 231 111
  2 Item2 222   0
  3 Item3 453 212
  4 Item4   0 765
  >
```

So in essence, the matrix' I have, each may or may not have same Item Names for the day, but the goal is to have them in one matrix/view and them see how the Items count rise/fall, etc.
[Suggestions for plot, graph etc to show useful information out of the data are also welcome]

Comment: Please show an exact representation of your matrices in R, e.g., add the output of `dput(yourmatrix1)` to your question. Right now it is unclear in which form your data is.

Comment: @Hasan Mahmud If it is a data.frame, you can do ` merge(Day1, Day2, by="name", all=TRUE)`

Comment: Welcome to SO. But this is one of the rare cases where you would have gotten immediate (and nice!) answers just [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+merge+in+r)

Comment: @Hasan Mahmud I guess the expected result you showed for Item3 & Item4 is the revese

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(plyr)
nm1 <- ls(pattern="^Day")
nm2 <- gsub("^(.).*(\\d)$", "\\1\\2", nm1)


res <- join_all(Map(function(x,y) {names(x)[2] <- y;x},
               mget(nm1), nm2), type="full")
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
res
#    Name  D1   D2
#1 Item1  231  111
#2 Item2  222   0
#3 Item3  453  212
#4 Item4   0   765
```

#### data

```
Day1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3"), Count = c(231L, 
222L, 453L)), .Names = c("Name", "Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

Day2 <-  structure(list(Name = c("Item1", "Item4", "Item3"), Count = c(111L, 
765L, 212L)), .Names = c("Name", "Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a package. With akrun's data:

```
datlist <- mget(ls(pattern="^Day"))

dat <- Reduce(function(DF1, DF2) merge(DF1, DF2, by = "Name", all=TRUE), datlist)
names(dat)[-1] <- names(datlist)
dat[,-1] <- lapply(dat[,-1], function(x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  x
})
#   Name Day1 Day2
#1 Item1  231  111
#2 Item2  222    0
#3 Item3  453  212
#4 Item4    0  765
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dflist = list(Day1, Day2)
dflist
for(i in 1:length(dflist)) {
    dflist[[i]]$day = paste0('Day',i)

}
merged = dflist[[1]]
for(i in 2:length(dflist)){
    merged = rbind(merged, dflist[[i]])
}

merged
   Name Count  day
1 Item1   231 Day1
2 Item2   222 Day1
3 Item3   453 Day1
4 Item1   111 Day2
5 Item4   765 Day2
6 Item3   212 Day2

dcast(merged, Name~day, value.var="Count")
   Name Day1 Day2
1 Item1  231  111
2 Item2  222   NA
3 Item3  453  212
4 Item4   NA  765
```